# How to unpack tuple in arguments with sugar in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

Is it possible to unpack tuple in arguments?

```
import sugar, sequtils

echo @[(1, 1), (2, 2)].filter((point) => point[0] > 1) # Works  
echo @[(1, 1), (2, 2)].filter(((x, y)) => x > 1)       # Error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sugar macro `=>` can *sort of* unpack tuple arguments, as the following example (taken from [docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sugar.html#%3D%3E.m%2Cuntyped%2Cuntyped)) shows:

```
proc passTwoAndTwo(f: (int, int) -> bool): bool =
  f(2, 2)

echo passTwoAndTwo((x, y) => x > 1) # true
```

Sort of, since it is actually treating x and y as two different arguments, not as element of a tuple.

In fact, the problem is the syntax `((x, y)) => x > 1` which is not supported by `=>` (you can check that by running it with a `discard` in front).

I am not sure how easy or reasonable would be to require `=>` to support the special case of passing a tuple.

For your use cases the following two lines are working alternatives once you have a `Point` type defined:

```
echo @[(1, 1).Point, (2, 2)].filter(point => point.x > 1)
echo @[(1, 1), (2, 2)].filterIt(it.Point.x > 1)
```